# Can I passthrough GPU into kvm without using vfio/iommu?

Tags: nvidia, kvm-virtualization, qemu, libvirt

Most of the tutorials I have seen are based on IOMMU to implement GPU passthrough. However, is there a way to bypass the IOMMU? My kernel is 5.15.126

---

Update 1:

From [libvirt.org](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html) I found that

> a <forward type='hostdev'> interface can have an optional driver sub-element with a name attribute set to either "vfio" (VFIO is a new method of device assignment that is compatible with UEFI Secure Boot) or "kvm" (the legacy device assignment handled directly by the KVM kernel module) Since 1.0.5 (QEMU and KVM only, requires kernel 3.6 or newer) . When specified, device assignment will fail if the requested method of device assignment isn't available on the host. When not specified, the default is "vfio" on systems where the VFIO driver is available and loaded, and "kvm" on older systems, or those where the VFIO driver hasn't been loaded Since 1.1.3 (prior to that the default was always "kvm").

But when I edit xml with the following format

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
  <driver name='kvm'/>
  <source>
    <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
  </source>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x08' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
```

I failed to start machine

```
error: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support legacy PCI passthrough
```

---

Update 2

According to the source code, it appears that libvirt 8.0.0 does not provide support for setting driver='kvm'. I'll try to downgra

```
domain_conf.c
case VIR_NETWORK_FORWARD_DRIVER_NAME_KVM:
            actual->data.hostdev.def.source.subsys.u.pci.backend =
                VIR_DOMAIN_HOSTDEV_PCI_BACKEND_KVM;
            break;

qemu_hostdev.c:
case VIR_DOMAIN_HOSTDEV_PCI_BACKEND_KVM:
        virReportError(VIR_ERR_CONFIG_UNSUPPORTED, "%s",
                       _("host doesn't support legacy PCI passthrough"));
        return false;
```

---

Update 3:

From libvirt release note

> v5.7.0 (2019-09-03)
>
> Remove KVM assignment support
>
> The KVM style of PCI device assignment was removed from the kernel in
> version 4.12.0 after being deprecated since 4.2.0. Libvirt defaults to
> VFIO for a long time. Remove support for KVM device assignment from
> libvirt too.

Also there are only 3 drivers which libvirt supports

```
/* the backend driver used for PCI hostdev devices */
typedef enum {
    VIR_DOMAIN_HOSTDEV_PCI_BACKEND_DEFAULT, /* detect automatically, prefer VFIO */
    VIR_DOMAIN_HOSTDEV_PCI_BACKEND_KVM,    /* force legacy kvm style */
    VIR_DOMAIN_HOSTDEV_PCI_BACKEND_VFIO,   /* force vfio */
    VIR_DOMAIN_HOSTDEV_PCI_BACKEND_XEN,    /* force legacy xen style, use pciback */

    VIR_DOMAIN_HOSTDEV_PCI_BACKEND_TYPE_LAST
} virDomainHostdevSubsysPCIBackendType;
```

After researching for an afternoon, it seems that the conclusion is: GPU passthrough without using VFIO passthrough is not possible without modifying the Linux kernel version 5.15.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is: GPU passthrough without using VFIO passthrough is not possible without modifying the Linux kernel version 5.15.

---

I have found a possible method related to VFIO's no-IOMMU mode. Currently, I'm stuck at one point. I will provide an update after experiments.

Failed. Seems Qemu 6.2.0 offers little to no support for no-IOMMU
In `hw/vfio/common.c`, VFIO_NOIOMMU_IOMMU type is not listed in the `iommu_types` array.

```
static int vfio_get_iommu_type(VFIOContainer *container,
                               Error **errp)
{
    int iommu_types[] = { VFIO_TYPE1v2_IOMMU, VFIO_TYPE1_IOMMU,
                          VFIO_SPAPR_TCE_v2_IOMMU, VFIO_SPAPR_TCE_IOMMU };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(iommu_types); i++) {
        if (ioctl(container->fd, VFIO_CHECK_EXTENSION, iommu_types[i])) {
            return iommu_types[i];
        }
    }
    error_setg(errp, "No available IOMMU models");
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

---

I would greatly appreciate if you could provide a better method.